# relation between ROI and wavelet transform output in jpeg2000

Tags: wavelet, roi, jpeg2000

Consider a single tile image.
I read that ROI involves scaling the coefficients in matrix obtained after wavelet transform.
My understanding is  - we shall multiply ROI related coefficients by power of 2 so that they will have greater precision then nearby unchanged coefficients.

My question is - suppose , I am encoder and I intend to focus a specific rectangular region in image then how do I know which coefficients I should manipulate ?

Thanks.